# Transform column into rows in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unpivot

I have a query in which I want some columns to be appear as rows.

The query is

```
Select * 
From Emp_mon_day 
Where emp_mkey IN (select emp_card_no 
                   from emp_mst 
                   where comp_mkey in (7, 110)) 
  and Year = 2016 and month = 2 
  and Emp_mkey = 2492
```

with this output being returned:

[image]

Now, I need to show columns `Day1, Day2, Day3` as rows in the output with the above query.

How to achieve that?

Comment: So do you want all columns till year and then two more columns `DayNo` and `Data` ?

Comment: Also how many days can be there ? 1-31?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: yes if all that I get then also good, other wise for `Day1`, Day2 will also do

Comment: @DhruvJoshi: all days, it depends on the month in the query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use case an `UNPIVOT` query like below

```
Select 
comp_mkey, 
fmodule_id,
fdepartment_id,
branch_mkey,
entry_department,
dept_mkey,
mkey,
emp_mkey,
entry_date,
month,
year,
day,
data
from
(select * from Emp_mon_day where emp_mkey IN 
(select emp_card_no from emp_mst where comp_mkey in
(7,110)) and Year = 2016 and month = 2 
and Emp_mkey = 2492) s
unpivot
(
data for day in ([Day1],[Day2]) -- dynamic query can generate all days data
)up
```

Below is sample test script and output

```
create table t(comp_mkey int,mont int,yea int,day1 varchar(10),day2 varchar(10))
insert into t values (2,2,2016,'AB','AC')

Select 
comp_mkey, 
mont,
yea,
day,
data
from
(select * from t) s
unpivot
(
data for day in ([Day1],[Day2]) -- dynamic query can generate all days data
)up
drop table t
```

**Output**

[image]

If you need all day's data you can either type out all expected columns in this statement

```
data for day in ([Day1],[Day2], [Day3],[Day4])
```

Better way would be to convert this into a dynamic query and apply logic for number of days expected in a month

Comment: @dhruv: one more thing i want in this is, I want to do the calculation of this employee in a query. how to do that

Comment: @coder You can pipe any query's output as source to the UNPIVOT syntax. Simply place your query inside the `(...)s` inner query. I'd suggest you see the syntax for `UNPIVOT` here [https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx]

Comment: @coder please share details on what you'd like help with

Answer (score 1):

CROSS APPLY can be proven helpful here.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emp]
(
    [comp_mkey]    [INT] NULL,
    [mont]         [INT] NULL,
    [year]         [INT] NULL,
    [day1]         [VARCHAR](10) NULL,
    [day2]         [VARCHAR](10) NULL
)

INSERT INTO emp VALUES (2, 2, 2016, 'AB', 'AC')
```

Use following Select statement

```
SELECT emp.comp_mkey
   , emp.mont
   , emp.year
   , emp_ext.[Day]
   , emp_ext.Value 
FROM emp
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES('Day1', emp.day1), ('Day2', emp.day2)
)emp_ext([Day], Value)
```

[image: result]